# Can St. Elmo's Fire cause instruments to fail?

Tags: radio-communications, flight-instruments

Can St. Elmo's Fire on an aircraft cause instruments to fail or give erratic readings, primarily with glass cockpits? Are there backup instruments that would not be affected? Does it affect radio transmissions?

Comment: You may want to check out the epic story of British Airways Flight 9 on Air Crash Investigations/Mayday.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the strong magnetic fields which are created can cause all of those problems if it gets bad enough.

To quote the AIM where they talk about Precipitation Static (which is one method of creating St. Elmo's Fire):

[**AIM 7-5-11. Precipitation Static**](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim/aim0705.html)

> b. A review of pilot reports often shows different symptoms with each
>   problem that is encountered. The following list of problems is a
>   summary of many pilot reports from many different aircraft. Each
>   problem was caused by P-static:
>
> 1. Complete loss of VHF communications.
>
> 2. Erroneous magnetic compass readings (30 percent in error).
>
> 3. High pitched squeal on audio.
>
> 4. Motor boat sound on audio.
>
> 5. Loss of all avionics in clouds.
>
> 6. VLF navigation system inoperative most of the time.
>
> 7. Erratic instrument readouts.
>
> 8. Weak transmissions and poor receptivity of radios.
>
> 9. "St. Elmo's Fire" on windshield.
>
> c. Each of these symptoms is caused by one general problem on the
>   airframe. This problem is the inability of the accumulated charge to
>   flow easily to the wing tips and tail of the airframe, and properly
>   discharge to the airstream.

Comment: I can say from personal experience that the radio interference can be deafening and make it exceptionally difficult to hear ATC.